# Difference between using local JS and JS from CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to write a JavaScript script to populate HTML using jQuery and Bootstrap. In many tutorials on the internet, tutors mention to using files from a Content Delivery Network(CDN) instead of calling those files locally.

But I am unable to foresee any advantage making a call to js or CSS over a network, instead of loading it locally, which should prove good enough.

I am eager to know, what is the difference in terms of network and machine resources as well as the load on a page.

Answer (score 3):

Pros using CDN:
* cache for the library in the client side.

Cons using CDN:
* If the cdn's site is down, your site will not get the files.
* Cdn file changes frequently and therefore your production site will work with the newest files that you didn't checked them(this can be very dangerous).

Now you can think if this suitable for your site.